# Forwarding references for non-reference types

Tags: c++

```
 template<typename T>
 void F(T&& x) {}
```

If we call it with argument of type int& everything is clear - reference collapsing takes place and we still have lvalue-reference. But what happens if we call it with, for example, int argument. My thoughts: we have deduced type T=int, decorate it with rvalue-reference, so F takes int&& argument and calling it with int type will result in error. But in real F takes such argument as lvalue-reference. Where does lvalue-reference come from? What rules did compiler apply to get int& from int?

Comment: "Universal reference" is a deprecated term. Say "forwarding reference" instead.

Comment: Edited, thank you.

Comment: Note that `&&` in a template means something different than a `&&` everywhere else.

Comment: @JiveDadson: Was it ever an official term? I thought it was a term invented by Scott Meyers as a teaching aid, and that it just didn't catch on.

Comment: @Christian - It was never official, but it is officially deprecated. (Snort.) Here is what the "deprecator" said: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf

Comment: @JiveDadson: That's a very good reference.

Comment: @Nikos C. That only because things referenced in Oliv's answer, right? (special rules for treatment of && in templates)

Comment: @M.M Edited, thank you.

Comment: The problem remains: arguments cannot have type `int&`.

Comment: @M.M But why? When i write int x = 1; int& y = x; f(y), I think argument has type int&.

Comment: @LPCWSTR it actually has type `int`.  The `&` in the declaration only refers to how the name is initially bound. After being bound it is no different to any other `int` .  You will see that `f(y)` behaves exactly the same as `f(x)` in every way (and if `int&& z = 3`, then `f(z)` resolves the same way as `f(x)` too)

Comment: @M.M "If an expression initially has the type “reference to T”, the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis."  So expression can have reference type. Am I missing something?
https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#5

Comment: @LPCWSTR that paragraph is specifying that if `x` was declared as `int&` then as an expression it has type `int` and value category *lvalue*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++17, there is the concept of *forwarding reference* in the C++ standard. Normaly the template parameter is deduced as a non reference. But for the specific case of a *forwarding reference* if the corresponding argument is a lvalue, the parameter is deduced as a reference. [C++ standard (N4700)[temp.over.deduct.call]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.call#3):

> [...]A *forwarding reference* is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a class template (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])). If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.[...]

For the concern of function call, it has the same meaning as this equivalent paragraph in the [C++11(N337)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.deduct.call#3) and [C++14(N414)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/temp.deduct.call#3) [temp.over.deduct.call]/3:

> [...]If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction[...]

Comment: C++11 had the same behaviour, just C++17 used different wording

Comment: @M.M. OK I had the reference for c++ 11 too.

Answer (score 0):

Forwarding references deduce lvalue reference for lvalues and rvalue reference for rvalues. For example, even for **lvalue** of type `int&&` it will still deduce `int&` (as it would for lvalue of type `int`), likewise, for **rvalues** of type `int` or `int&&` it will deduce `int&&`:

```
template<typename T>
class show;

template<typename T>
void F(T&& x) 
{ show<decltype(x)>();}

int main() {
    int&& x = 5;
    F(x);
}
```

> ```
> main.cpp:6:3: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'show<int &>'
> ```

```
int main() {
    F(5);
}
```

> ```
> main.cpp:6:3: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'show<int &&>'
> ```

```
int main() {
    int x = 5;
    F(x);
}
```

> ```
> main.cpp:6:3: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'show<int &>'
> ```

```
int main() {
    F([]()->int{return 5;}());
}
```

> ```
> main.cpp:6:3: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'show<int &&>'
> ```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I know that, but AFAIK there are no special rules in standard for forwarding references. But they still work: they are based only on reference collapsing which presents even in C++98. I want to know how they work in that case: not only that they deduce lvalue for lvalues but how we get int& from int (what rules did compiler applied to get int& from int).

Comment: There is no such thing as "lvalue of type int&&" or "rvalue of type int&&". Expressions never have reference type.